# Inequality regarding summation and division

Tags: inequality, summation

I need your expertise on solving this problem:

Let $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $b \geq a$ $d = n \cdot c$ where $n \in Z^+$.

What is the upper bound for $y \in \mathbb{R}^+$ such that:
$$ \frac{a+c}{b+d} \geq y \cdot \left( \frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d}\right)$$

Please advise.

Comment: What is $n$? If $n$ is just $(ad)/c$, what is its significance to the main question?

Comment: I have edited the question regarding $n$, thanks for clarifying that!

Comment: The number $n$ is fixed or it is used only to formulate a condition $ad/c\in\Bbb Z^+$?

Comment: Yes, $n$ is fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We start from the following sequence of equivalent transformations

$ \frac{a+c}{b+d} \geq y  \left( \frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d}\right)$

$(a+c)bd \geq y(b+d)(ad+bc)$.

$(a+ad/n)bd \geq y(b+d)(ad+bad/n)$.

If $a=0$ then $c=0$ and the inequality holds for each $y\in\Bbb R^+$.

Otherwise divide both its sides by $ad$:

$(1+d/n)b \geq y(b+d)(1+b/n)$.

Now we see that LHS  linearly depends on $b$, whereas
if $y>0$ then RHS quadratically depends on $d$. So if we put $d=1$ and $b$ tending to infinity, RHS will be eventually bigger than LHS. Thus $y=0$.